# How to solve quadratic inequality $(a \pm b)^2 \le (c \pm x)^2$?

Tags: inequality

How can one solve for $x$ the inequality $(a \pm b)^2 \le (c \pm x)^2$? If squares were not there, one could easily break $(a + b) \le (c + x)$ and $(a - b) \le (c - x)$, and then solve as usual. But the square seem to make it complicated.

Comment: What do you mean by the $\pm$'s? Is this a collection of four different inequalities? Two different inequalities? Do you want them to hold simultaneously, or do you want to solve the different inequalities separately?

Comment: Yeah, I want to treat them as four different inequalities.

Comment: $$(a+b)^2≤(c+x)^2$$
Tells you that 

$$a+b≤c+x \text{ or } -(a+b)≥c+x$$

Same goes for the three other equations

Comment: Ok, if $x^2 \le y^2$, then  $x\le y$ is clear to me. How do you conclude the second?

Comment: It should not be clear to you, because it is not correct actually. If $-x>y$, you also have $x^2<y^2$

Comment: @BarbaudJulien, I think your last statement is not true. If $x=-3$, $y=2$, then not only $-x>y$ is true but also $x^2 >y^2$ is also true.

Comment: use $x^2 >y^2$ then $(x-y)(x+y)\ge0$